# How to Lookup using view

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I went through the method of automatic look up here: http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php?title=Lookups.

What I am trying to achieve is that automatic look up using the view instead of table.

Do you have any idea for that?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you did not read all the way to the bottom to see the link to [SysTableLookup](http://www.axaptapedia.com/SysTableLookup_class)?